# Code from Blazor documentation throwing exception. Details are in description

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Below block of code is from Blazor documentation. @bind attribute throwing exception. I am trying to understand how data binding works. What I am missing in blow block of code?

```
@page "/test"

<input @bind="CurrentValue" />

@code {
    private string CurrentValue { get; set; }
}
```

Exception: 
 [image]

Comment: The code you show here should not cause this error. Restart Visual Studio and reproduce this in a _new_ app.

Comment: When this persists, verify you have the right SDK installed. Repair if in doubt. If you can't resolve it then add all relevant versions to the question.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I tried multiple times restarting visual studio but no luck. I will check the versions.

Comment: Also create a fresh _new_ project. Note the template version in the dialog where you chose Server/Wasm.

Comment: Delete *bin*, *obj* and *.vs* folders and rebuild using `dotnet build` command.

Comment: @HenkHolterman It's started working after creating new project.

Comment: That happens. I do regularly delete the `.vs` folder too, om the first signs of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

When you have compilation trouble with VS you don't understand

Delete *bin*, *obj* and *.vs* folders and rebuild using `dotnet build` command.

If the compilation issue persists, read carefully the stack trace and you find your error.